# Power in regular expression

Tags: regex

In this regular expression [(\d*)[\^*{2}](\d*)](https://regex101.com/r/bL1qQ8/4) I'm trying to capture digits of a power formula: for example 2^3 should return 2 and 3, and 4**5 should return 4 and 5. The expression only works in the first case, any ideas?

Comment: Your link to regex101 describes it perfectly. The regex is wrong for what you try to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*{2}` bit isn't doing what you think it's doing because it's in a class (`[]`). It will accept each individual character in the class (the only meta characters in classes are `^` and `-`). So your expression will accept 121, 1{4 etc. Probably something like this:

```
(\d+)(?:\^|\*{2})(\d+)
```

Is nearer the mark.

Comment: My ▲ goes to this one as @migg's solution have bugs in it.

Answer (score 1):

This would be correct:

```
(\d*)(?:\^|\*{2})(\d*)
```

You are literally matching everything inside your `[]` which is not what you want.

Comment: Though @ig0774 have similar solution to yours but `*` does makes difference in searching. It will also allow first or last digit to be `optional` as if not present and hence matches `**5` , `2**`, `^4`, `**`, `^`.

Comment: @noob You are right. I tried to keep it close to the original because OP does not state if e.g. `^5` should be matched or not. The problem was clearly between the `[]`. So "bug" is a bit of a stretch IMHO.

Comment: When I said **bug** I meant unexpected behavior.

Comment: I agree but then what is the expected behaviour? It's not clear.

Comment: Expected is regex should only return numbers when they are separated by either `^` or `**`.